# Building upon existing function

Tags: python, function

I was just playing around with functions in order to further my understanding of them and I was curious, is it at all possible to return the users first name and last initial using the following function without adding any additional functions?

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your full name: ")

def username(a):
    print(a[0:6]+a[-1])
username(name)
```

Comment: yes it is possible, you will probably have to modify your splices though

Comment: By last initial, do you mean the first letter of their last name?  `a[-1]` gets the last letter of the string, which will be the last letter of their last name

Comment: Do you count things like `split` as a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the length of input names can vary and number of names then you will have to use another function `split` and `index`. If the user can just enter a single name you will need to add an `if` or `try...except`.

`a[:a.index(' ')])` will get the first name, from the beginning of the input to the first space

> `index` returns ValueError if the character isn't found so if they might enter just first name surround with try...except

`a.split()[-1][0]` will get the first letter of the last name even if they enter more than two names (Billy Bob Joe -> Billy J)

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your full name: ")

def username(a):
    print(a[:a.index(' ')]+' '+a.split()[-1][0])
username(name)
```

Comment: Thanks @depperm , your answer have actually helped broaden my understanding of how to apply those features to my studies.

Answer (score 0):

Your current function assumes a length of first and last name.  You could try
print(a.split()[0] + ' ' + a.split()[1][0]).  The split() will change the string to a list of two elements, element 0 is the first name and element 1 is the last name.

a[-1] will give you the last letter of your string, which it sounds like you don't want this for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your full name: ")                                                                                                                                  

def username(a):                                                                                                                                                                   
    fullname = a.strip().split(' ')                                                                                                                                                

    if len(fullname) < 2:                                                                                                                                                          
        print('Error: last name required')                                                                                                                                         
        print('Type: firstname <middle name> last name')                                                                                                                           
        exit(1)                                                                                                                                                                    

    try:                                                                                                                                                                           
        print('%s %s' % (fullname[0], fullname[-1][0]))                                                                                                                            

    except IndexError:                                                                                                                                                             
        exit(1)                                                                                                                                                                    

username(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have managed to implement the info that you folk have provided me.

```
'''
code to input full name and convert into username consisting of first + first
initial of last name or first and first initial of first name if input is one name.
'''
def fullname():
    name = raw_input("Please enter your full name: ").lower()
    try:
        name = (name[:name.index(' ')]+''+name.split()[len(name.split())-1][0])
    except:
        name = name[0:]+name[0]
    return name

# code to generate exponential numbers
def print_exponential():
    base = int(raw_input("Please select a base number: \n"))
    power = int(raw_input("Please select a power number: \n"))
    exponential = 1
    while power>0:
        exponential = exponential * base
        print base
        if power >1:
            print "*"
        power = power -1
    print "=%d" % exponential



'''
code to generate interactive menu with an error return for incorrect selection and exit clause.
'''
ans=True
while ans:
    print ("""
    U.Create a Username
    E.Run Exponential Calculator
    Q.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=raw_input("What would you like to do? ").upper()
    if ans=="U": 
      print fullname()
    elif ans=="E":
      print print_exponential()
    elif ans=="Q":
      print("\n Goodbye")
      break
    elif ans !="":
      print("\n Error: Choice must be U, E or Q")
```